# Any Git LFS Alternatives that are compatible with Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, github, large-files, git-lfs

I created a simple node/express HTML5 video application over the weekend and I wanted to put my code on GitHub as well as deploy it on Heroku. The problem is that my application serves movie trailers (average 2 mins each), in the mp4 format, and are too large to upload to github without using something like git lfs.

From reading the Heroku docs, it seems git lfs is not compatible with that platform. What should I do here? Are there alternative services like git lfs and heroku that would allow me to upload my code to a repository like github and deploy it on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check out Microsoft GVFS(Git virtual file system): https://aka.ms/gvfs
Gvfs package is available for heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages

Comment: I down-voted because it does not answer the question. Please check whether GVFS is compatible with Heroku and, if so, update the answer.